# The method 'getSupportFragmentManager()' is unsupported

Tags: android, datepicker

So i'm trying to enable datepicker for android versions bellow 11. for that i'm using support library v4. I import all the thing necessary:

```
import android.support.v4.app.*;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
```

And i created a class:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class DatePicker extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener  {

public EditText textField;  

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}


public EditText getTextField() {
return textField;
}


public void setTextField(EditText textField) {
this.textField = textField;
}


public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
textField.setText(day+"."+(month+1)+"."+year);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {
textField.setText(arg3+"."+(arg2+1)+"."+arg1);
}
}
```

So class compile ok. But the problem is when i try to use it. I have an onclick method for edittext that looks like that:

```
public void showDatePicker(View v) {
    DialogFragment selectDate = (DialogFragment) new DatePicker();
    EditText edit=(EditText)v;
    ((DatePicker) selectDate).setTextField(edit);
    selectDate.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

however in last line i get the error:

```
The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity
```

Any ideas how to resolve that? btw i don't have imported anything like

```
android.app.Fragment;
```

So that is not the case here :S

Comment: You should actually accept the answer for others indicating that this is a solved problem

Comment: So I did, luckily I'm passed that now :D

Answer (score 67, accepted):

My guess is that your `MainActivity` is not extending `FragmentActivity`! In the SupportPackage an Activity must inherit from FragmentActivity to get Methods like `getSupportedFragmentManager()`.

EDIT:

Since your Activity is inheriting from another class, you can try to implement the Behavior of one of these classes and kind of merge them. I.e here you'll find the code for FragmentActivity:
[FragmentActivity Source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java)

Comment: wow that's true but i'm activity is extending SherlockMapActivity, and since java only enable to extend one activity i don't have idea how to fix that :S

Comment: @gabrjan: You cannot readily use the Android Support package's fragments with the Maps SDK add-on. Hence, AFAIK, `SherlockMapActivity` only works on API Level 11+ and inherits from `MapActivity`, so you would use `getFragmentManager()`, not `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: well that's not true sherlockmapActivity works just fine on api level 8 ... since i tried it and it's just working ok.

Comment: It's known issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/actionbarsherlock/YuFCY7mjP5Q, https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock-Plugin-Maps/issues/1

Comment: so no way to do that? I understand why it's working because i wasn't using fragments anywhere...

Comment: lately i'm runing into so many things that can't be done easy that i'm going to start hatting android...

Comment: what if i do something lieke that: private SherlockFragmentActivity SFA; private SherlockFragmentActivity SFA; and then SFA.getSupportedFragmentManager() it crashes now but is there a way to make it work?

Comment: @gabrjan..There were so many huge changes to API 11+ that it seems "ok" to just set your manifest's min SDK to 11.  I just started Android dev after 3 years of iOS and am frustrated myself.  Forgetting about Gingerbread is a choice you need to make, but in my case, I'm not going to support Gingerbread for this type of reason (also eliminating tons of layout folders port/land/large/blah/blah).  Here is a great article that might put your mind at ease a little for the future of android: http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/04/jelly-bean-reaches-1-in-4-android-devices-tablets-lag-at-10-percent/