# Error in getSupportFragmentManager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Why I am getting an error message showing change getSupportFragmentManager() to getFragmentManager()

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: show your error catalog

Comment: The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity.

Comment: I would check your imports and make sure you have `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` instead of `android.app.FragmentManager` imported

Comment: But it showing error while I am trying to import SupportFragmentManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here FragmentActivity docs:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java

You issue  is MainActivity is not extending FragmentActivity and SupportPackage an Activity must inherit from FragmentActivity to get Methods like getSupportedFragmentManager().Activity is inheriting from another class, you  implement one of  classes and kind of merge them.

May be possible  answer here

[The method 'getSupportFragmentManager()' is unsuported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121432/the-method-is-getsupportfragmentmanager-is-unsuported)

Comment: Yeah, thnx. It's working now. I import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager as well as extends FragmentActivity and my problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

MainActivity must extend FragmentActivity

Comment: Although S.Swain got there first (his answer was not there when I entered mine), this answer is correct.  Why the "not useful" downvote?